# Can I see my own votes after an election is closed?

Tags: support, election

I'd like to revisit my own vote after the final results are in. Is this possible?
<sub>No, I didn't take a screenshot</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**

The election on Example.SE is over and you want to know whom you voted for. Steps to follow (thanks @animuson):

1. Go to `https://example.stackexchange.com/election/`
2. Select the respective election page
3. There are still the tabs like "Nomination", "Primary" and "Election" right above the candidates' posts - choose *Election*

In case you know the election's number (e. g. 1), you can go directly to `https://example.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election`.

(Another way is to track down the official moderator election results post on the respective stack's meta page. There's also a link to the election page.)

I managed to do so (testing it on a beta site - Parenting.SE's 2018 pro tem election). I went to the [2018 Community Moderator Election Results](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1248/30519) meta post, which has a link to the election page. I followed it and clicked on the *Election* tab. There I can still see my votes.

I also tested it on a random site and can access the [Election tab](https://askubuntu.com/election/6?tab=election) even in the case of Ask Ubuntu.SE which I'm not a member of.

Comment: Great, thx - how did you find out about the `?tab=election` part of that link? Because https://askubuntu.com/election/6 does not show my votes.

Comment: @guntbert without `?tab=election`, you end up in the Nomination tab, which has no voting. `?tab=election` takes you to the Election tab, which is the phase where you get 1st Choice, 2nd Choice, and 3rd Choice votes.

Comment: You don't really need to track down the meta announcement. You can just go to `/election` and choose the election from there. That page displays a list of past elections when there is not an active election going on.

Comment: @animuson Thank you! I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Ahh, **now** I was able to see the "tabs" you mentioned - they are very easy to overlook with the current design. [barely visible tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPd37.png)